# Postgresql and pgvector: the extention vector is not available

Tags: postgresql, vector-database, pgvector

```
from llama_index.indices.vector_store import VectorStoreIndex
from llama_index.vector_stores import PGVectorStore
import textwrap
import openai

import os

import sys
sys.getdefaultencoding() 


os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "KEY"
openai.api_key = "KEY"

## Load documents 
documents = SimpleDirectoryReader("./data/paul_graham").load_data()
print("Document ID:", documents[0].doc_id)

## Create the database 
import psycopg2

connection_string = "postgresql://postgres:123456@localhost:5432"
db_name = "vector_db"
conn = psycopg2.connect(connection_string)
conn.autocommit = True

with conn.cursor() as c:
    c.execute(f"DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS {db_name}")
    c.execute(f"CREATE DATABASE {db_name}")

## Create the index 
    
from sqlalchemy import make_url

url = make_url(connection_string)
vector_store = PGVectorStore.from_params(
    database=db_name,
    host=url.host,
    password=url.password,
    port=url.port,
    user=url.username,
    table_name="paul_graham_essay",
    embed_dim=1536,  # openai embedding dimension
)

storage_context = StorageContext.from_defaults(vector_store=vector_store)
index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(
    documents, storage_context=storage_context, show_progress=True
)
query_engine = index.as_query_engine()
```

I am having this error when running the code above, I would like to know how to install this **vector** extention, thanks.

*psycopg2.errors.FeatureNotSupported: ERROR: Extension 'vector' is not available
DETAIL:  Could not open extension control file "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/16/share/extension/vector.control": No such file or directory.
HINT:  Extensions must first be installed on the system where PostgreSQL is running.*

When I am compiling pgvector files  **make install**, I am facing this error

"process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, uname -s, ...) failed.
Makefile:16: pipe: No error
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, uname -m, ...) failed.
Makefile:24: pipe: No error
Makefile:48: C:/PostgreSQL/16/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target 'C:/PostgreSQL/16/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk'.  Stop."

Comment: *HINT: Extensions must first be installed on the system where PostgreSQL is running.* Since I see `C:\...` I'm going to assume  you installed Postgres using the EDB installer. I would start by seeing if `pgvector` is offered via the StackBuilder app that ships with the EDB install.

Comment: I have checked the StackBuilder app,  under the **Spatial Extentions** , there is only this Extention: PostGIS 3.4.1 bundle includes PostGIS 3.4.1

Comment: What makes you think it is a spatial extension? Per [pgvector](https://github.com/pgvector/pgvector): *Open-source vector similarity search for Postgres*

Comment: It is not available in the stuckBuilder, for Installing it I used: pip install pgvector

Comment: I have also tried the installaions instrections https://github.com/pgvector/pgvector , however when I used **make install** I am having this error: process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, uname -s, ...) failed.
Makefile:16: pipe: No error
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, uname -m, ...) failed.
Makefile:24: pipe: No error
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, pg_config --pgxs, ...) failed.
Makefile:47: pipe: No error
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.

Comment: `pip` is for installing Pyhon packages so that is not going to work for a Postgres extension. In order to run `make` you will need to have the  Postgres and Windows development environment installed and I doubt you do.

Comment: The steps I followed was: 1. Download PostgreSQl version 16.1 for windowsx86-64 using EDB installer
2. Install PostgreSQL
3. Downloading the pgvector extension files
4. Compiling them with the PostgreSQL server (here I am having the error when running **make install** , therefore  I am not able to compile the pgvector extention files with the PostgreSQL server).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256588/discussion-between-fatima-fatima-and-adrian-klaver).

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

To solve this issue, I followed the installations method for windows https://github.com/pgvector/pgvector#windows.

Note: I run the command line a adminstrator.